# Two conditions function is not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, combobox

I've created two conditions function in javascript. The first function is when user fill opsi combobox "Internal" then field pengirim internal disabled = false. And then the second function is when user have filled combobox "Internal" and field pengirim internal still null or not filled. Then user get notification that field pengirim internal must required value. I don't know why, please advice me

```js
// jika dipilih opsi internal maka field pengirim internal enabled. field pengirim eksternal disabled 
$("#opsi").change(function() {
  if ($("#opsi").val() === "Internal") {
    document.getElementById('pengirim_internal').disabled = false;
    // disabled field pengirim internal dan clear pengirim eksternal
    document.getElementById('pengirim_eksternal').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('pengirim_eksternal').value = '';
  }
  elseif
  $("#validation-form").validate({
    rules: {
      pengirim_internal: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      pengirim_internal: "Silahkan Pilih Pengirim Internal!",
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="hr">
  <label class="span2">Opsi Surat Masuk</label>
  <select name="opsi" id="opsi">
     <option value="">Pilih Satu</option>
     <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
     <option value="Eksternal">Eksternal</option>
    </select><span class="mandatory">*</span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="hr">
  Pengirim Internal :
  <select id="pengirim_internal" name="pengirim_internal">
        <option name="pengirim_internal" value="Islam">Example1</option>
        <option nama="pengirim_internal" value="Kristen">Example2</option>
        </select>
  <span class="mandatory">*</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: There is no `elseif` in JavaScript. It’s `else if` and the condition needs to be wrapped in parentheses. What even is the condition after the `elseif` and what is the code to be executed? Or did you just mean `else`?

Answer (score 0):

With the code that you have given, I hope this will works for you,

```
//jika dipilih opsi internal maka field pengirim internal enabled. field pengirim eksternal disabled 
$("#opsi").on('change',function() {
    if ( $("#opsi").val() === "Internal" ) {    
           $('#pengirim_internal').prop('disabled',false);
           // disabled field pengirim internal dan clear pengirim eksternal
           $('#pengirim_eksternal').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
           $('#pengirim_eksternal').val('');
        } 
    else
    {
        $("#validation-form").validate({
        rules: {
            pengirim_internal: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            pengirim_internal: "Silahkan Pilih Pengirim Internal!",
        },      
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Make sure to add jquery and jquery.validate.min.js references to your page.